# Limpiar texto(string) en python

Tags: python, pytesseract, tesseract

tengo el siguiente codigo el cual uso para extraer texto de imagenes el problema es que Tesseract no extrae correctamente, ya que confunde simbolo y demas con caracteres que no corresponden sin mencionar imprime lineas en blanco, para todo esto estoy implementando expresiones regulares para limpiar el texto, ahora tengo el siguiente problema tras hacer la limpieza del texto me aparecen lineas repetidas.

```
    for imagenes in listadeimagenes:
        preprocess = "thresh"
        img = cv2.imread(path + "/" + imagenes)
        cv2.imshow('imagen de la ruta', img)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        if (preprocess == "thresh"):
            gray = cv2.threshold(
                gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
        elif (preprocess == "blur"):
            gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 3)
        filename = "{}.png".format(os.getpid())
        cv2.imwrite(filename, gray)

        imgtext = Image.open(filename)

        pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'
        # limpio el codigo de caracteres que no corresponden
        texto1 = pytesseract.image_to_string(imgtext)
        texto = re.sub(r'[^\da-zA-Z0-9_() \n]+', '', texto1)
        text = re.sub(r'\n\s*\n', '\n', texto)

        # elimino las lineas que no tengan atributos
        largo = 0
        s = text
        nueva = ""
        for i in s.split('\n'):
            largo = 0
            for j in i.split(' '):
                largo += len(j)
                if (largo >= 5):
                    nueva = nueva + i + '\n'

        print("Linea original:\n", s)
        print("linea nueva:", nueva)
#elimino simbolos o palabras de menos de 1 caracter
        cadenanueva= re.compile(r'\W*\b\w{1}\b ')
        nueva1 = cadenanueva.sub('', nueva)

        print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("   *  *  T E X T    D E T E C T E D  *  *")
        print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
# pregunto de hay texto para extraer
        if nueva1:
            contenidolineas = nueva1.splitlines()
            palabras = contenidolineas[0].split(" ")
            mensaje2 = ""
            for i in contenidolineas:
                # pregunto si esta linea esta vacia
                if contenidolineas:
                    if (contenidolineas.index(i) == 0):
                        mensaje2 = mensaje2 + f"Entidad: " + contenidolineas[0]
                    else:
                        mensaje2 = mensaje2 + f"\nAtributo: "

                        palabras = i.split(" ")
                        for j in palabras:
                            if (palabras.index(j) == 0 and contenidolineas.index(i) != 0):
                                mensaje2 = mensaje2 + f"{j} tipo "
                            else:
                                mensaje2 = mensaje2 + f"{j} "
                else:
                    contenidolineas.pop(i)

            print(mensaje2)
            print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
```

Esta es una de las imagenes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el texto original que obtengo con la funcion image_to_string:

```
 |_

J:| Dimcus|?‘omer V

Customer|D INT

FirstName VARCHAR(45)

LastName VARCHAR(45)

ZipCode VARCHAR(45)

City VARCHAR(45)


State VARCHAR(45)


"I |'| I’
```

este es el texto que obtengo de la consulta, como pueden ver el nombre de la entidad se repite en la misma linea y las demas se repiten las lineas

```
Entidad: Dimcusomer VDimcusomer V

Atributo: CustomerD tipo INT

Atributo: CustomerD tipo INT

Atributo: FirstName tipo VARCHAR(45)

Atributo: FirstName tipo VARCHAR(45)

Atributo: LastName tipo VARCHAR(45)

Atributo: LastName tipo VARCHAR(45)

Atributo: ZipCode tipo VARCHAR(45)

Atributo: ZipCode tipo VARCHAR(45)

Atributo: City tipo VARCHAR(45)

Atributo: State tipo VARCHAR(45)

Atributo: State tipo VARCHAR(45)
```

Comment: Eso que muestras es el resultado de aplicar el OCR o el de aplicar tu programa sobre el resultado del OCR? Ya que no todos tenemos instalado tesseract, si el problema es con tu código, la imagen de entrada no es muy útil. Sería mejor que además proporcionaras la cadena que procesas y la cadena que te resulta.

Comment: Ahi agregue el texto original que obtengo al aplicar la funcion image_to_string sobre la imagen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que el problema está en el preproceso que haces aquí:

```
        for i in s.split('\n'):
            largo = 0
            for j in i.split(' '):
                largo += len(j)
                if (largo >= 5):
                    nueva = nueva + i + '\n'
```

Aunque el código es bastante difícil de seguir, supongo que lo que en realidad querías hacer es esto otro:

```
        for i in s.split('\n'):
            largo = 0
            for j in i.split(' '):
                largo += len(j)
            if (largo >= 5):
                nueva = nueva + i + '\n'
```

Es decir, al estar el `if` al mismo nivel que el `for j` (y no indentado dentro de él como tú tenías), añadirás la línea actual (contenida en `i`) sólo después de computar el `largo` total, si ese largo es mayor de 5.

Tal como tú lo tenías, la línea era añadida en cada iteración del `for j`, si la longitud era mayor de 5. Ya que `j` itera por palabras, si la primera palabra tenía longitud mayor de 5, se añadiría a `nueva` la línea completa. Y sin importar el tamaño de las siguientes palabras, se volvería a añadir la línea completa otra vez por cada palabra encontrada (pues la longitud total seguirá creciendo por encima de 5 a medida que se comprueban palabras).

### Actualización

No he podido resistirme a refactorizar tu código para usar menos variables y con nombres más significativos, para eliminar la concatenación de cadenas que es ineficiente (cambiándolo por listas que luego se juntan en una sola cadena con `.join()`) y para eliminar el uso de `.index()` que tampoco es muy eficiente y en todo caso no era necesario.

```
texto = texto1
texto = re.sub(r'[^\da-zA-Z0-9_() \n]+', '', texto)
texto = re.sub(r'\n\s*\n', '\n', texto)

# elimino las lineas que no tengan atributos
lineas_bien = []
for linea in texto.split('\n'):
    largo_palabras = 0
    for palabra in linea.split():
        largo_palabras += len(palabra)
    if (largo_palabras >= 5):
        lineas_bien.append(linea)


#elimino simbolos o palabras de menos de 1 caracter
a_eliminar = re.compile(r'\W*\b\w{1}\b ')
resultado = a_eliminar.sub('', "\n".join(lineas_bien))

print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
print("   *  *  T E X T    D E T E C T E D  *  *")
print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
# pregunto de hay texto para extraer
if resultado:
    mensaje = []
    es_primera = True
    for linea in resultado.splitlines():
        if not linea:
            continue
        if es_primera:
            mensaje.append(f"Entidad: {linea}") 
        else:
            palabras = linea.split()
            mensaje.append("Atributo: {}".format(
                " ".join([palabras[0], "tipo", *palabras[1:]])))
        es_primera = False

    print("\n".join(mensaje))
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
```

Comment: gracias, ya funciono, parece que todavia no me acostumbro bien a python y a su forma de cerrar procesos, funciones y de mas estructuras

Comment: @AgustinCoronel Recuerda aceptar la pregunta si resolvió tu problema o duda.